# Folner sequence: construct through semidirect product; proof understanding help

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, limits, proof-verification

Sorry I have difficulty finding anything relevant on Folner sequence. I am reading [this](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional/#more-1354) and come up against lemma 4.

I have not studied much algebra, so I might interpret this wrong, but the lemma appear to say that if a countable $G=H\rtimes K$ such that $H,K$ both have Folner sequence, then $G$ also have a Folner sequence. Now I have a number of question about the proof:

1. The proof use a function $f(n)$ that is supposed to be rapidly increasing. When I try to work out the details, it seems like $f$ being the identity function always work. Surely a function don't just get introduced pointlessly like that. So what went wrong?
2. Why is axiom of choice needed to pick an inverse, considering $G$ is countable, and thus can be well-ordered without axiom of choice?
3. Did I interpret the lemma correctly?

Finally, if you can find another proof of this, written out in more details, it would be great. I have trouble finding the proof, considering that the lemma does not even have a name.

Thank you.

Comment: For Qn 1, $f(n)=n$ would work for a direct product $H \times K$, but not necessarily for a semidirect product. For $g \in G$ and $x \in G$, $g\phi(x) = \phi(gx)k$ for some $k \in H$, so left translating $F_n$ by an element of $G$ results in the elements of $A_{f(n)}$ being left translated by $|B_n|$ elements of $H$. So you need $f(n)$ to be suitably large for it to work. I don't know the answer to your Qn 2.

Comment: Oh wow, I found the errors. Such an elementary error, I guess I shouldn't have modeled the proof after a concrete example of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks a lot.